# Date Display Null

Tags: ios

This is my date format function. This code work perfectly in my simulator and device but not in my friend device in Denmark.
I called this function for two different date in same class but for one date it's work perfect but for another it returns null.
I get both date from database using web service.
My Friend used iPhone 4s with iOS 7.0

```
-(NSString*)DateFormat:(NSString *)str{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSa"];
    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:str];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    str = [formatter stringFromDate:date1];    
    return str;
}
```

Comment: try to set [formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]]; keyur

Comment: I try it also but still it return nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(NSString*)DateFormat:(NSString *)str{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSa"];
    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:str];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    str = [formatter stringFromDate:date1];    
    return str;
}
```

Comment: i add this [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]]; and it's work

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSString*)DateFormat:(NSString *)str{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSa"];
    NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:str];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
    NSString * result = [formatter stringFromDate:date1];    
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First debug the code, check you are getting dates in same format or in different formats or nil value. If dates will be in different format, then you have to keep it in **if condition** to get correct date. If you get **nil** value you cannot format date otherwise your method is correct.

Comment: Yes harikrishna, I already check it. Both date formats are same.